# Discrepancy in definition of quantum reed muller codes

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

I'm reading through this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.09333.pdf) and on page 14 they define quantum reed muller (QRM) codes using the classical versions. I've seen punctured RM codes used to define quantum CSS codes with good properties; but the paper's definition is with
unpunctured codes. I checked the the $X$ and $Z$ stabilizers define a QECC; but the definition of the $X$ and $Z$ logicals doesn't seem right. For one, they don't have the same dimensions. They're also orthogonal...which also doesn't make sense. Is the paper wrong or did I miss something?
(the motivation is that these codes allow some transversal non-clifford gates)

I converted the accepted answer to [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/). Here's my version :

```
    Qrm:=function(m,r)local s,mat,layers,Sx,Sz,Lx,Lz,mx,mz,kx,kz,check,verify,code;
     mat:=Iterated(List([1..m],x->[[1,1],[0,1]]),KroneckerProduct); # 2^m x 2^m matrix = m-th tensor power of [[1,1],[0,1]]
     layers:=List([0..m],x->Filtered(mat,y->Sum(y)=2^(m-x)));       # layer[r]=subset of rows with weight = 2^(m-r)
     s:=m-r-2;
     Sx:=Concatenation(layers{[1..r+1]});  mx:=Length(Sx);            # X satbilisers
     Sz:=Concatenation(layers{[1..s+1]});  mz:=Length(Sz);            # Z satbilisers
     Lx:=layers[r+2];                      kx:=Length(Lx);            # X logicals
     Lz:=layers[s+2];                      kz:=Length(Lz);            # Z logicals
    
     Print("n =",2^m," |Sx|=",mx," |Sz|=",mz," |Lx|=",kx," |Lz|=",kz,"\n");
    
     check:="kx=kz=k; k=Binomial(m,r+1); k=n-(mx+mz);";verify:=kx=kz and kx=Binomial(m,r+1) and 2^m-(mx+mz)=kx;Print(verify," ",check,"\n");
     check:="Sx*Sz=0; ";verify:=\mod(Sx*TransposedMat(Sz),2)=NullMat(mx,mz);Print(verify," ",check,"\n");
     check:="Lx*Sz=0; ";verify:=\mod(Lx*TransposedMat(Sz),2)=NullMat(kx,mz);Print(verify," ",check,"\n");
     check:="Lz*Sx=0; ";verify:=\mod(Lz*TransposedMat(Sx),2)=NullMat(kz,mx);Print(verify," ",check,"\n");
     check:="Lx*Lz=I; ";verify:=\mod(Lx*TransposedMat(Reversed(Lz)),2)=IdentityMat(kz);Print(verify," ",check,"\n");
    
     code:=rec();
     code.Sx:=Sx;code.Sz:=Sz;code.Lx:=Lx;code.Lz:=Lz;
     return code;
    end;
```

I checked with a few other parameters :

```
gap> code:=Qrm(6,1);;
n =64 |Sx|=7 |Sz|=42 |Lx|=15 |Lz|=15
true kx=kz=k; k=Binomial(m,r+1); k=n-(mx+mz);
true Sx*Sz=0; 
true Lx*Sz=0; 
true Lz*Sx=0; 
true Lx*Lz=I; 
gap> code:=Qrm(6,2);;
n =64 |Sx|=22 |Sz|=22 |Lx|=20 |Lz|=20
true kx=kz=k; k=Binomial(m,r+1); k=n-(mx+mz);
true Sx*Sz=0; 
true Lx*Sz=0; 
true Lz*Sx=0; 
true Lx*Lz=I; 
gap> code:=Qrm(6,0);;
n =64 |Sx|=1 |Sz|=57 |Lx|=6 |Lz|=6
true kx=kz=k; k=Binomial(m,r+1); k=n-(mx+mz);
true Sx*Sz=0; 
true Lx*Sz=0; 
true Lz*Sx=0; 
true Lx*Lz=I;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find the paper that you cite the most accessible, although it's filled with good stuff!

As far as I can see, it works out, perhaps after a little muddling of whether you want the generator/parity check matrix of a given code (it seemed to be the opposite of what I was expecting). This possibly made my Mathematica code below more complex than necessary (attempting to extract logical operators from parity check matrices rather than generators!)

```
(*construct generator of classical RM code*)
RM[r_, m_] := 
 If[r == 0, {Table[1, {2^m}]}, 
  If[r == m, IdentityMatrix[2^m], 
   ArrayFlatten[{{RM[r, m - 1], RM[r, m - 1]}, {0, 
      RM[r - 1, m - 1]}}]]]
AX = RM[1, 6]; (*X stabilizers*)
excess = RM[2, 6];
positions = 
  Ordering[#, -1][[1]] & /@ 
   NullSpace[LinearSolve[Transpose[excess], #, Modulus -> 2] & /@ AX, 
    Modulus -> 2];
logicalX = excess[[positions]];
AZ = RM[3, 6]; (*Z stabilizers*)
excess = RM[4, 6];
positions = 
  Ordering[#, -1][[1]] & /@ 
   NullSpace[LinearSolve[Transpose[excess], #, Modulus -> 2] & /@ AZ, 
    Modulus -> 2];
logicalZ = excess[[positions]];
Print["Is definition of X stabilizer correct size? ", 
 Dimensions[logicalX] == {15, 64}]
Print["Is definition of Z stabilizer correct size? ", 
 Dimensions[logicalZ] == {15, 64}]
Print["Do logical Z commute with X stabilizers? ", 
 Count[Mod[RM[1, 6].Transpose[logicalZ], 2], 1, Infinity] == 0]
Print["Do logical X commute with Z stabilizers? ", 
 Count[Mod[RM[3, 6].Transpose[logicalX], 2], 1, Infinity] == 0]
Print["Do the anticommutations between logical X and logical Z have \
full rank (therefore defining correct number of qubits? ", 
 Abs[Det[Mod[logicalZ.Transpose[logicalX], 2]]] == 1]
```

---

Previous version (not relevant to question)

So, to define the 15 qubit triorthogonal code, we specify the $X$ stabilizers with the generators
$$
A_X=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that all the rows have even weight. This part of the code is easily seen to be distance 3 because all of the columns are distinct (so $Z$ errors will all have distinct syndromes).

The logical operators are
$$
X_L=X^{\otimes 15},\qquad Z_L=Z^{\otimes 15}.
$$
These clearly anti-commute with each other, and commute with the X-type stabilizers (in the case of $X_L$ this is trivial. For $Z_L$ it's because of the even weight of the stabilizers).

The $Z$ stabilizers are then just selected to be what they have to be in order to define a code such that they all commute with the $X$ stabilizers and $X_L$. I don't remember what these are, but they're easily calculated (e.g. in Mathematica):

```
AX = Transpose[Rest[Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]]];
XL = Table[1, {15}];
AZ = NullSpace[Append[AX, XL], Modulus -> 2]
```

to find that
$$
A_Z=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Again, every column is distinct, so the distance of this part of the code is at least 3 (I believe it's actually distance 7 for $X$ errors).

Comment: This is a different construction; I'm familiar with it but it's based on *punctured* RM codes. There's a closed form definition of the $X$ and $Z$ stabilizers and logicals and I can generate this family already and everything checks out for it. Your example corresponds to punctured $RM(m=4,r=1)$; Steane code to $RM(3,1)$;...However all these codes have $k=1$; the codes in that paper are not punctured (so $n=2^m$ not $2^m-1$) and the logicals would have $k>1$ if the definition is correct. That's what got me interested; but it seems there's something wrong with the definition of the logicals.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks for the very nice answer. It does seem to work; I think the problem in the paper is that they refer to the logicals as RM(m,x) but that really should be RM(m,x+1)-RM(m,x).  I think the NullSpace calculations on "excess" in your code just removes RM(m,x). I ran your mma code and it does work; GAP is my preferred platform so I adapted your solution to GAP. I'll edit my question to add the GAP solution for reference. There's a lucky coincidence in that if you reorder the Z logicals the the X and Z logicals obey the expected commutation relations....thanks again.

Comment: as a side note, I like to calculate the destabilisers for the codes I'm looking at. Together with the stabilizers and logicals you get a full set of generators of the Pauli group. The encoding operation becomes an automoprhism of the group. I can get these through calculations similar to your Nullspace calculations but for these codes I have a feeling there's a closed form solution. Let me know if you see a quick way to get these destabilsers given the relationships between the different RM's...